# Replacing facebook share icon with font-awesome facebook icon

Tags: css, facebook, font-awesome

I have been trying to add facebook share functionality for my webapp. I wanted to replace the default icon with that of font-awesome icon whose HTML is given below:

```
 <a href="#" id="fb-link">  
          <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
          </span>
     </a>
```

Though may not be necessary, let me share facebook share icon code I have been using:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="icon"></div>
```

I am preferably looking for a solution that avoids making an image from font awesome icons.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook says no.  https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts "Don't: Use any icons, images or trademarks to represent Facebook other than what is found on this resource center"